# Increment variable in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Java, something like `i++` would increment `i` by 1.

How can I do in Ruby? Surely there has to be a better way than `i = i + 1`?

Comment: This doesn't show a lot of effort. Google would have turned up numerous hits for "[ruby increment operator](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+increment+operator)" including "[No increment operator (++) in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717519/no-increment-operator-in-ruby)", plus the afore-mentioned question.

Comment: I think this is a different question.  He's asking how you do it, not why there is no support for it.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.ruby-doc.com/docs/Newcomers/ruby.html#operators),

> Ruby has no pre/post increment/decrement operator. For instance, x++ or x-- will fail to parse

So, you can do

```
i += 1
```

which is equivalent of `i = i + 1`

Comment: does this create new memory?  str = str + 'a'

Comment: but i need to initialize i before?

Comment: This sucks for a language emphasising on writing less code.

Comment: Varun Garg I agree as well since many other languages have this feature, but I also understand they wanted to keep it simple, but then I feel like Ruby has enough of it's own quirks to complicate it in it's own special way lol.