# Ruby: "Unexpected keyword_end"... but all openers and closers match

Tags: ruby, syntax-error, keyword

I'm working on a block of code that will return the nth prime to the user. I'm getting "unexpected keyword_end" syntax errors for lines 19 and 22. I put comments in the code so you can find the locations of the errors easily.

```
def nthPrime(n)
    number = 3
    primeNumber = 1
    i = 0
    primes = [2]
    #Iterates the number until we've found the desired number of primes.
    while primeNumber < n
        #Iterates through the prime numbers already found to locate prime factors.
        while i < primes.length
            #Returns TRUE if a prime factor is found.
            #If no prime factors are found, primeNumber ticks up by one, and the number
            #is added to the list of primes.
            if number % primes[i] != 0
                if i == primes.length
                    primes << number
                    i = 0
                else
                    i ++
                end #Unexpected keyword_end
            end
            number ++
        end #Unexpected keyword_end
    end
    puts number
end

nthPrime(6)
```

I've looked at a lot of other Stack Overflow questions about the "unexpected keyword_end" error, but all of those issues were caused because the authors had too many "end"s in their code. I believe, after checking many times, that I have the right number of "end" closers in my code

What else could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write `i ++` as `i += 1` and `number ++` as `number += 1`. Ruby don't support `++` or `--` operators. Read this question [No increment operator (++) in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717519/no-increment-operator-in-ruby) and also read [Why doesn't Ruby support i++ or i— (increment/decrement operators)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660563/why-doesnt-ruby-support-i-or-i-increment-decrement-operators)

Comment: That fixed my problem. Thanks a lot! It's been a while since I touched Ruby, and I totally forgot that the increment operators are different.

Comment: I went ahead and did it. I tried to do it after I got your answer, but you're not allowed to approve of an answer within 15 minutes of posting a question, so I went to sleep. Thanks again!