# For loop inside if/else inside while. Proper syntax

Tags: ruby, loops, for-loop

Why doesn't this work? I'm getting unexpected keyword_end.

```
while(!k && DATA[q])
    if DATA[q] == 'aa' && DATA[p] == 'aa'
        pl = DATA[r]
        for i in 0..pl
            PACK[i] = DATA[i+4]
        end

        k+=1 #end while 
    else
        q++
        p++
        r++
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You are getting error because `++` does not work in Ruby.

> Ruby has no pre/post increment/decrement operator. For instance, x++
>   or x-- will fail to parse. More importantly, ++x or --x will do
>   nothing! In fact, they behave as multiple unary prefix operators: -x
>   == ---x == -----x == ...... To increment a number, simply write x += 1.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3717565/3035830) (which indeed are the [words of Ruby's author](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/2710)  himself.)

You should replace them as follows:

```
q+=1
p+=1
r+=1
```

Comment: My love and gratitude

Comment: There are other syntax errors in the code. You solved only a part of the problem.

Comment: was my answer factually incorrect? I cant understand the reason for downvote.

Comment: No reason for downvoting here

Comment: I got it. You need to edit your answer, so I can revoke my downvote.

Comment: Since OP is new to Ruby, my answer explains him how increment operators works here, which seemed to the main issue with his approach. I hope that was useful. :)

Comment: It is indeed. Sorry, I thought your answer was incomplete.

Comment: Upvoted since the answer makes sense. I really can't understand these serial downvoters.

Comment: No issues. Thanks for agreeing at last.. :D

Comment: @SimoneCarletti You're a bit late to the party. I corrected.

Comment: @shivam You need to edit your answer, so I can upvote. My vote is locked.

Comment: @shivam Can you do me a favor? I need one more downvote, so I can delete my post and get a Peer Pressure Badge. Would be cool.