# Ruby break expression acting weird

Tags: ruby

```
require 'csv'

i = 0
CSV.foreach("survdata.csv", headers: true) do |row|
  puts row
  i++
  if i > 1 then
    break
  end
end
```

This looks so simple, and yet it doesn't run. Can you see why I am getting:

```
/mydev/surveyresult/surveyresult.rb:11: void value expression
```

Comment: FWIW: There's no `++` operator in ruby: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717519/no-increment-operator-in-ruby

Comment: @orde That is related, but is not the reason.

Comment: Oh is my face red! Thanks @stackoverflow! (I've been teaching Java the last 3 months and my ruby mental database has been corrupted!!!)

Comment: @pitosalas If you are really a professor (or even if you are actually not), please be politically correct.

Comment: @sawa: i try not to offend. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @pitosalas See the edit that I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby does not support `i++` syntax as a shortcut to `i+=1`. See "[Why doesn't Ruby support i++ or i-- (increment/decrement operators)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660563/why-doesnt-ruby-support-i-or-i-increment-decrement-operators)" for more information why.

You can fix your code like this:

```
require 'csv'

i = 0
CSV.foreach("survdata.csv", headers: true) do |row|
  puts row
  i = i+1
  if i > 1 then
    break
  end
end
```

More information on the error message (thanks sawa):

Ruby does actually support `i++` syntax. If it is followed by `x`, it is interpreted as unary operator `+` applied to `x`, whose result passed as an argument to `i+`. In your example, `if i > 1 then; break; end` does not return any value, hence the error message "void value expression".

Comment: To be strict, your answer is wrong. If Ruby did not support such construct syntactically, then it would raise a syntax error, but it doesn't. It does support `i++` syntax. If it is followed by `x`, it is interpreted as unary operator `+` applied to `x`, whose result passed as an argument to `i+`.

Comment: Fair strict point. However there was no `x` here, can we agree to say it won't work as expected by the author ?

Comment: `x` in this case is `if i > 1 then;  break; end`. Furthermore, this does not answer the question why the OP is getting "void value expression". Along the lines of your answer, can you answer why it did not raise a syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby doesn't have an increment operator the last time I looked.

In place of

```
i++
```

do

```
i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is because the:

```
if i > 1 then
  break
end
```

part breaks, which does not have a return value (within the code block in question). And you cannot apply the unary operator `+@` to something that lacks a value, nor can `i.+` take the return value of such as an argument.

Comment: Why was this down voted? Despite the accepted answer has a clearer explanation this one is also correct.