# Why I'm getting void value expression although I have assigned value

Tags: ruby

I am new into ruby. I have the following code block:

```
a = 10

while a < 20 do
 puts "True"
a++

next unless a == 12
puts "This is not 12"
end


$end
```

However, I'm getting void value expression for `a ==12`.I have assigned 10 into it to begin with so I don't see why I'm getting void value.

Comment: `++` operator doesn't exist in Ruby

Comment: `$end` would raise an exception if  `aa` were replaced by `a  += 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `a++` by `a += 1`
should work.

Ruby has no `++` operator.
[No increment operator (++) in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717519/no-increment-operator-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose

```
a = 2
```

The following are all equivalent, returning `5`.

```
a++ 3
a + +3
a + +
3
a++

3
```

Therefore,

```
a++

next unless a == 12
```

is the same as

```
a + +next unless a == 12
```

This generates a `"void value expression"` exception because `next unless a == 12` does not return a value (to be sent to the method `:+`).

The fix, of course, is to replace `a++` with

```
a = a + 1
```

or its abbreviated form

```
a += 1
```