# Why does ruby interpret ++ as +@

Tags: ruby

I am getting bizzare output in irb

```
>> [1, 2] + + [3]
NoMethodError: undefined method `+@' for [3]:Array
    from (irb):2
    from /home/marko/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
>> [1, 2] ++ [3]
NoMethodError: undefined method `+@' for [3]:Array
    from (irb):3
    from /home/marko/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
>>
```

Is this happening on purpose or is it a bug?
What's the logic behind converting `+ +` into `+@`

Comment: In the past year the authors of 453 SO questions suggested that unexplained behavior might be attributed to a bug in Ruby. The culprit was found to be something more mundane in 451 of those cases.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Numeric.html#method-i-2B-40

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not converting `+ +` into `+@`, it's converting the latter `+` to `+@`, i.e. the prefix `+` operator. Thus the expression is parsed the same as `[1, 2] + (+[3])`.

(`+@` is used to denote the unary plus operator because `+` is reserved for the binary plus operator.)

(Also, there's no `++` operator in Ruby.)

Comment: Why is `+` same as `+@`?

Comment: Because `+` denotes the binary plus operator, while `+@` denotes the unary (prefix) plus operator.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this is parsed as:

```
[1, 2] + +[3]
```

And the error is Ruby telling that there is no concept of a positive array.

You can see this with integers. For example:

```
1++2  # => 3
# parsed as 1 + +2
# (obviously this is a particularly bad way to write this expression - don't do it!)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this answer [No increment operator (++) in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717519/no-increment-operator-in-ruby) Ruby does not have an incremental operator, so at best `+ +` will be interpreted as two separate operators, causing unexpected behavior. As

> ++ and -- are NOT reserved operator[s] in Ruby

it's possible that a Ruby gem or other included library could cause additional unexpected behaviour when attempting this operation. Also worth noting is that `++` or `+ +`, which is functionally the same thing in a non white-space sensitive language like Ruby will fail to parse where there are no possible separate operations for both the `+` operators.

In short: ***Ruby* does not interpret `+ +` as `+@`, it merely interprets it as two separate `+` operators.**

Comment: This is misleading. First: Yes, Ruby *does* interpret it as two separate operators, but it interprets it as two *different* operators: binary infix `+` and unary prefix `+`. Second: the message corresponding to unary prefix `+` is called `+@`, so, yes, Ruby *does* interpret it as `+@`, specifically as `[1, 2].+([3].+@())`.

Comment: Is this always true, or just in certain situations? If the latter then my answer to the original question asked is accurate and should not be misleading, since it concerned a generalization made from a specific example, rather than the example itself -- though of course the tuple_cat answer from a more experienced dev with lower-level experience is worthy of its upvotes, imo.