# Why doesn't reduce return the initial value if the block never changes the accumulator?

Tags: ruby

Consider the following irb loop:

```
irb(main):015:0> [nil, nil].reduce(0) { |accum, x| accum + 1 unless x.nil? }
=> nil
```

Why does this return `nil` instead of `0`?

According to the Ruby Enumerable documentation:

> If you specify a block, then for each element in enum the block is passed an accumulator value (memo) and the element. If you specify a symbol instead, then each element in the collection will be passed to the named method of memo. In either case, the result becomes the new value for memo. At the end of the iteration, the final value of memo is the return value for the method.

My expectation would be that the accumulator should get set to `0` before the array starts to get folded, since that is given as the initial value. Then, the block's escape clause will trigger for all elements in this array, so the accumulator will never change. Finally, since `0` is the last value stored for the accumulator, it should be returned.

Comment: "Then, the block's escape clause will trigger for all elements in this array" – And what is the return value of the block (and thus the value of the accumulator) in that case?

Comment: The short answer is that `accum + 1 unless x.nil?` is the same as `x.nil? ?
 nil : (accum + 1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever the block returns is going to be the next accumulator value.

And you return `nil`:

```
'whatever' unless true #=> nil
```

You could do this:

```
arr.reduce(0) { |a, e| e.nil? ? a : a + 1 }
```

Or this:

```
arr.compact.reduce(0) { |a, e| a + 1 }
```

Or this:

```
arr.compact.size
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense; thanks! To summarize the conceptual mistake I made: the accumulator is the return of each call to the block, not a boxed value in memory that gets changed by side effect and then returned at the end of the `reduce` call.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce *starts* with the accumulator you pass but then sets it to whatever the block returns.

It might be helpful to see what it does internally (this is not the actual source code but a simple reproduction):

```
class Array
  def my_reduce(memo, &blk)
    each { |i| memo = blk.call(memo, i) }
    memo
  end
end
```

Here's some examples to show its usage:

```
# with 0 as starting memo
[nil, nil].reduce(0) { |memo, i| i ? memo + 1 : memo } # => 0
[nil, nil].reduce(0) { |memo, i | memo += 1 if i; memo; } # => 0
[nil, nil].reduce(0) { |memo, i| memo + (i ? 1 : 0) } # => 0

# with [] as starting memo
[1,2].reduce([]) { |memo, i| memo.push(i + 1); memo } # => [2,3]
[1,2].reduce([]) { |memo, i| memo.concat([i + 1]) } # => [2,3]
[1,2].reduce([]) { |memo, i| memo + [i + 1] } # => [2,3]
[1,2].reduce([]) { |memo, i| [*memo, i + 1] } # => [2,3]
```

You can see how only some of these require `memo` to be returned as the last line. The ones that don't are taking advantage of methods which return their modified objects, instead of relying on mutability (`memo.push`) or local variable assignment (`memo += 1)`

[each_with_object](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Enumerable/each_with_object) is basically the same thing as reduce except that it automatically returns the accumulator from each block, and reverses the order of the block args (`|i, memo|` instead of `|memo, i`). It can be nice syntactic sugar for reduce when the memo is a mutable object. Returning the memo from the block is no longer necessary in the following example:

```
[1,2].each_with_object([]) { |i, memo| memo.push(i + 1) } # => [2,3]
```

However it won't work with your original example, because the memo (a number) is immutable:

```
# returns 0 but should return 1
[true, nil].each_with_object(0) { |i, memo| memo += 1 if i }
```

to say `memo += 1` here is nothing but local variable assignment. Remember, you can never change the value of `self` for an object in ruby, not even a mutable one. If Ruby had increment operators (`i++`) then it might be a different story (see [no increment operator in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717519/no-increment-operator-in-ruby))

Comment: Insightful; thanks! I'll keep in mind `each_with_object` as well in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectations are correct but the missing piece is considering what the block returns after execution.

In Ruby the last thing to execute is returned and this code: `accum + 1 unless x.nil?` returns `nil`.

Just for science here's an example:

```
irb(main):051:0> puts 'ZOMG' unless nil.nil?
=> nil
```

Because `nil` is returned by the block your accumulator's initial `0` is overwritten with `nil`.

If you modify the code to return the accumulator you will get `0` as expected:

```
irb(main):052:0> [nil, nil].reduce(0) do |accum, x|
irb(main):053:1*     accum + 1 unless x.nil?
irb(main):054:1>     accum
irb(main):055:1> end
=> 0
```