# Ruby Parenthesis syntax exception with i++ ++i

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

Why does this throw a syntax error? I would expect it to be the other way around...

```
>> foo = 5
>> foo = foo++ + ++foo                                                  
=> 10 // also I would expect 12...                                                                   
>> foo = (foo++) + (++foo)                                              
SyntaxError: <main>:74: syntax error, unexpected ')'                    
      foo = (foo++) + (++foo)                                           
                   ^                                                    
<main>:75: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
```

Tried it with tryruby.org which uses Ruby 1.9.2.

---

In C# (.NET 3.5) this works fine and it yields another result:

```
var num = 5;
var foo = num;
foo = (foo++) + (++foo);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(foo); // 12
```

I guess this is a question of operator priority? Can anybody explain?

For completeness...
**C** returns 10
**Java** returns 12

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Ruby support i++ or i-- for fixnum?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660563/why-doesnt-ruby-support-i-or-i-for-fixnum)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no `++` operator in Ruby. Ruby is taking your `foo++ + ++foo` and taking *the first* of those plus signs as a binary addition operator, and the rest as unary positive operators on the second `foo`.

So you are asking Ruby to add 5 and (plus plus plus plus) 5, which is 5, hence the result of 10.

When you add the parentheses, Ruby is looking for a second operand (for the binary addition) before the first closing parenthesis, and complaining because it doesn't find one.

Where did you get the idea that Ruby supported a C-style `++` operator to begin with? Throw that book away.

Answer (score 12):

Ruby does not support this syntax. Use `i+=1` instead.

As @Dylan mentioned, Ruby is reading your code as `foo + (+(+(+(+foo))))`. Basically it's reading all the `+` signs (after the first one) as marking the integer positive.

Comment: @Simon: It thinks you mean `foo + (+(+(+(+foo))))` (basically applying a positive sign to the second `foo` four times and adding it to the first `foo`). Ruby doesn't support `foo++` or `++foo`.

Answer (score 6):

Ruby does not have a `++` operator. In your example it just adds the second foo, "consuming" one plus, and treats the other ones as unary + operators.