# How to increment an integer in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What causes the error in the following code?

```
ruby -e "puts 1++"
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected $end
```

or

```
ruby -e "x=1; puts x++;"
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected ';'
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Ruby doesn't have an `++` operator. You can do `puts 1.next` though. Note that for your second example this would not change the value of `x`, in that case you'd have to use `x += 1`.

Comment: you mean, ruby doesn't have ++ operator?

Comment: Exactly, it has neither an increment nor a decrement operator. Look at this post to see why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660563/why-doesnt-ruby-support-i-or-i-for-fixnum