# Ruby while errors

Tags: ruby, debugging, while-loop

Ruby, which is normally very forgiving, is giving me an error on a while loop; I can't see why.

```
def foo(vals)
  n = vals.length
  key = n-1
  newkey = n-1

  while ((key > 0) && (vals[key] <= vals[key-1])) key--

  key
end
```

The error:

```
prog.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do_cond or ';' or '\n'
    while ((key > 0) && (vals[key] <= vals[key-1])) key--
                                                       ^
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby incrementing integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993915/ruby-incrementing-integer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby has no pre/post increment/decrement operator. We use `x -= 1`
and paste it before while if you want one liner.

```
def foo(vals)
  n = vals.length
  key = n-1
  newkey = n-1

  key -= 1 while ((key > 0) && (vals[key] <= vals[key-1]))
  key
end
```

Comment: Huh, good to know.
I actually tried putting it before, but was still using the increment operator.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby may be sometimes *forgiving*, but not about non-existing operators: `key--` -> `key -= 1`

You are using Ruby as it were a low level language (as C), a more idiomatic (and functional) approach:

```
def foo(vals)
  (vals.size - 1).downto(1).detect { |idx| vals[idx] > vals[idx-1] } || 0
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby doesn't have the `--` or `++` unary operators, nor the `while` syntax you're trying to use. Try this instead:

```
while key > 0 && vals[key] <= vals[key - 1] do key -= 1 end
```

As @IgorKapkov suggests you can also turn it around, which is more Rubyish:

```
key -= 1 while key > 0 vals[key] <= vals[key - 1]
```

Comment: "_But beware, this does have different semantics since the part before while will be executed before the first test of the conditional that follows._" It's not true. For example: `x = 1 ; puts "first" while x < 1 ; while x < 1 do puts "second" end` it's the same.