# Why doesn't the shorthand arithmetic operator ++ after the variable name return 2 in the following statement?

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple arithmetic operator but am at my wits end why it doesn't return 2. The code below returns 1. I thought that x++ equates to x = x + 1;

**CODE**

```
var x = 1;
document.write(x++);
```

However if I run the code as follows, it returns 2 as expected

**CODE**

```
var x = 1;
document.write(++x);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Xander - I am aware they are to do with post increment and pre-increment however don't quite understand why do most articles often reference x++ as being the same as x = x+1? That makes no sense when they don't return the same values.

Comment: It has the same effect of incrementing the number by 1. However, it doesn't have the same effect when used inside an expression.

Comment: @nhahtdh - Can you give an example?

Comment: `(x++) * (x++)` compared to `(x = x + 1) * (x = x + 1)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### PostIncrement(variable++) & PostDecrement(variable--)

When you use the `++` or `--` operator after the variable, the variable's value is not incremented/decremented until after the expression is evaluated and the original value is returned. For example `x++` translates to something similar to the following:

```
document.write(x);
x += 1;
```

### PreIncrement(++variable) & PreDecrement(--variable)

When you use the `++` or `--` operator prior to the variable, the variable's value is incremented/decremented before the expression is evaluated and the new value is returned. For example `++x` translates to something similar to the following:

```
x += 1;
document.write(x);
```

The postincrement and preincrement operators are available in C, C++, C#, Java, javascript, php, and I am sure there are others languages. According to [why-doesnt-ruby-support-i-or-i-increment-decrement-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660563/why-doesnt-ruby-support-i-or-i-increment-decrement-operators), Ruby does not have these operators.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean `after` the statement? So x++ is not the same as x = x + 1 then?

Comment: I think you have it backwards. `++` before increments the variable in-place.

Comment: @Josh Mein - Can you elaborate what you mean by `it is not incremented until after the statement is executed`?

Comment: "After the statement is executed" sounds fishy to me. The increment in postfix operators happens right after the value is given to the expression. `x = 1; x++ * x++` will give 2.

Comment: @nhahtdh Is evaluated a better term in your opinion?

Comment: @Josh Mein - So is this just limited to Javascript or do the same rules apply across the board i.e. PHP, Ruby, Perl, etc?

Comment: @Josh Mein - Do the same rules apply when using `x--` and `--x`?

Comment: @JoshMein: I am not sure about the meaning of "statement". In this code `x++ * x++;`, I don't think statement refers to `x++` only, but it may refer to the whole `x++ * x++`. I cannot find any reference for this, though.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Check the documentation for different languages. If they leave postfix `++` and `--` implementation defined, then you should avoid using it within an expression.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey I have updated my answer regarding what languages support it. Note I have only included the ones I know, but I am sure there are more.

Comment: @nhahtdh I have updated statement to expression. Is that better?

Comment: The postfix operator is implementation defined in C/C++, so it is very dangerous to use within expression. As for "expression", it still refers to the whole `x++ * x++`. (According to MDN: An expression is any valid unit of code that resolves to a value.)

Comment: @nhahtdh Do you have a better suggestion? I started looking after you mentioned it and most places use expression to describe it.

Comment: @JoshMein: I think it is fine if you say that `<variable>++` or `<variable>--` (variable only - multiple `++` and `--` is not valid **in Javascript**) expression resolves to the old value in the `<variable>`, and the variable is incremented/decremented by 1.

Answer (score 9):

I think of `x++` and `++x` (informally) as this:

**`x++`**:

```
function post_increment(x) {
  return x; // Pretend this return statement doesn't exit the function
  x = x + 1;
}
```

**`++x`**:

```
function pre_increment(x) {
  x = x + 1;
  return x;
}
```

The two operations do the same thing, but they *return* different values:

```
var x = 1;
var y = 1;

x++; // This returned 1
++y; // This returned 2

console.log(x == y); // true because both were incremented in the end
```

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at the [javascript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) pages 70 and 71 you can see how it should be implemented:

**Prefix:**

> > 1. Let expr be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
> > 2. Throw a SyntaxError exception if the following conditions are all true:72 © Ecma International 2011
> >
> >    - Type(expr) is Reference is true
> >    - IsStrictReference(expr) is true
> >    - Type(GetBase(expr)) is Environment Record
> >    - GetReferencedName(expr) is either "eval" or "arguments"
> > 3. Let oldValue be ToNumber(GetValue(expr)).
> > 4. Let newValue be the result of adding the value 1 to oldValue, using the same rules as for the + operator (see 
> >        11.6.3).
> > 5. Call PutValue(expr, newValue).
> > 6. Return newValue.

Or more simply:

1. Increment value
2. Return value

**Postfix:**

> > 1. Let lhs be the result of evaluating LeftHandSideExpression.
> > 2. Throw a SyntaxError exception if the following conditions are all true:
> >
> >    - Type(lhs) is Reference is true
> >    - IsStrictReference(lhs) is true
> >    - Type(GetBase(lhs)) is Environment Record
> >    - GetReferencedName(lhs) is either "eval" or "arguments"
> > 3. Let oldValue be ToNumber(GetValue(lhs)).
> > 4. Let newValue be the result of adding the value 1 to oldValue, using the same rules as for the + operator (see 
> >        11.6.3).
> > 5. Call PutValue(lhs, newValue).
> > 6. Return oldValue.

Or more simply:

1. Assign value to temp
2. Increment value
3. Return temp