# Why Events[--i] returns a value but Events[i-1] does not

Tags: javascript

I write a discord bot and have this function that gets called upon a command.
but the return values of Event[--i] and Event[i-1] are completely different.

```
TIMEDURATION = 500;
Events = [];

const deleteAllEvents = (channelID, commandID) =>{
    for(i=1;i<Events.length+1;i++){
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log(Events[--i], Events[i-1]);
            bot.deleteMessage({
                channelID,
                "messageID" : Events[--i]
            })
        }, (TIMEOUTDURATION*i));
        setTimeout(()=>{
            bot.deleteMessage({
                channelID,
                "messageID" : commandID
            }, ()=>{
                Events = []
            })
        }, TIMEOUTDURATION*Events.length+1)
    }
}
```

The expected output would be :

and is if `Events[--i]` is used:

`[Contents of Events(array)]`

but is:

`undefined`

for each iteration if `Events[i-1]` is used.

the contents are Long numbers called `Snowflakes`stored as strings in the array.

[Why doesn't the shorthand arithmetic operator ++ after the variable name return 2 in the following statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218299/why-doesnt-the-shorthand-arithmetic-operator-after-the-variable-name-return)

this has nothing to do with it. The problem is that let

```
i=3
console.log(--i) ==> 2
```

and

```
i=3
console.log(i-1) ==> 2
```

should return the same thing but

```
Events[--i]
```

and

```
Events[i-1]
```

do not return the same thing but they should. In fact 1st statement has a valid return value while 2nd returns undefined.

when you run just the code it actually runs fine but if used in conjunction with the rest it doesn't but i cannot see a problem with the surrounding code.
for anyone interested i post it to GitHub.

Comment: --i leads to i being reduced by one permanently..

Comment: Gitrepo: https://github.com/Kazumasan/stack

Comment: @Estradiaz I know thats why Events[i-1] but that only returns undefined but should give the same index right ?

Comment: Your `i` is a global variable, which makes everything more complicated.

Comment: but its the only loop i have so why is that a problem events is also global but it seems that its not accessible within the timeout function...

Comment: I guess first of all you should fix your loop to use the conventional `for(i=0;i<Events.length;i++){`. That'll cause your timeout code to always log the last event, not `undefined` - do log `Events.length` and the value of `i` itself to understand why.

Comment: Not sure if you solved your issue yet - but consider using debugger to trace down your issue

Comment: Already did it doesn't really help much when entered Events[--i] The result is as expected for the first iteration and Event[i-1] still returns undefined i just cant see how the array reference Events[i-1] can be undefined while i = 1 and Events will still return the array but i worked around it now. And when you run the snippet in any environment it works fine so i don't see a problem in the code i posted.