# syntax errors syntax error, unexpected keyword_end

Tags: ruby

What is wrong here?

```
  def get_some_elements(arr)
      sz=arr.size
      arr2 =Array.new(sz)
      i=0
    j=0
    0.upto(sz-1) do |i,j, arr2|
      arr2[i] =arr[i][j]
      i++
      j++
    end
end

get_some_elements([[2,4,6], [3,5,7], [12,14,16]])
```

The error messages I get are

```
10: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
16: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660563/why-doesnt-ruby-support-i-or-i-increment-decrement-operators

Comment: @sawa, why would you say that? :)

Comment: This is only barely Ruby code. You probably need a better reference to learn from.

Comment: The [Pickaxe Book](https://pragprog.com/book/ruby/programming-ruby) is a fantastic introduction.

Answer (score 2):

```
  i++
  j++
```

Remove it, and your code won't have error messages. But you need to re-write it.

Comment: i think the first comment explain this, you need not put it as answer!

Comment: []': no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError) is what I got after removing i++ and j++

Comment: @NaimRajib If it's the answer, then it should go into an answer. Whether or not someone mentioned it in the comments is irrelevant.

Comment: @Azolo, I think Naim's point is a comment is sufficient for pointing out a trivial error. Giving an answer that parrots an earlier comment, especially when the problem is obvious, may enhance Reputation, but (imo) is not so good for reputation.

Comment: @NaimRajib To paraphrase Horton the Elephant, "An answer is an answer, no matter how small."  Comments cannot have a checkmark, but answers can.  See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments