# SyntaxError on rails in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have this function in my model on Rails, what i pretend to do is that it returns the two first categories not deleted and with some articles, but when i run the app, it gives to me this error

```
/Users/juampi/Desktop/iaw2015/app/models/category.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end end ^
```

/Users/juampi/Desktop/iaw2015/app/models/category.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end end ^

here is the model category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy
validates_uniqueness_of :nombre 

def PrimerasDosNoVacias
    cant=0
    aux =0
    cate=["",""]
    categorias = Category.where(eliminado: false)
    while (categorias.length >= aux && cant < 2) 
        if (Article.where(category_id: categorias[aux].id).length != 0)
            cate=categorias[aux]
            cant++
        end 
        aux++
    end
end

end
```

the view where i called the method

```
..      <% categories = Category.PrimerasDosNoVacias %> ..
```

Comment: Not sure how you can call this method as a class method?  Is that a typo?  ps - Ruby uses naming conventions where method names are always lower cased and underscored (not camel cased like you have).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby does not support the `++` operator. 
Change it to `+=1`

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy
validates_uniqueness_of :nombre 

def PrimerasDosNoVacias
    cant=0
    aux =0
    cate=["",""]
    categorias = Category.where(eliminado: false)
    while (categorias.length >= aux && cant < 2) 
        if (Article.where(category_id: categorias[aux].id).length != 0)
            cate=categorias[aux]
            cant+=1
        end 
        aux+=1
    end
end

end
```

[Why doesn't Ruby support i++ or i-- (increment/decrement operators)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660563/why-doesnt-ruby-support-i-or-i-increment-decrement-operators)

Comment: great! begginner error... it's ok the way i called it on the view?

Comment: No problem, "Juampi". We are here to help :)

Comment: Sorry, the way you called what on the view?

Comment: in the home view, when i called the method, as i show in the post, now its says "undefined method `primerasdosnovacias' for #<Class:0x007fe0bca9dd10>"

Comment: Oh, ok. The way you declared it, this is an instance method. To use it, you will need to instantiate a new object first. If you want this to be a `class` method, you should define it like this: `def self.PrimerasDosNoVacias`

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` is missing a `do`:

```
while (categorias.length >= aux && cant < 2) do
```

Comment: i changed it but i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Ruby doesn't have a `++` operator. Instead of doing e.g. `cant++`, do `cant += 1`:

```
if (Article.where(category_id: categorias[aux].id).length != 0)
  cate = categorias[aux]
  cant += 1
end
aux += 1
```

Comment: great!, thats is, do you know why now it's says "undefined method `PrimerasDosNoVacias' for #<Class:0x007fe0b9864678>" ?

Comment: `def PrimerasDosNoVacias` defines an instance method, i.e. you call it on an instance of the `Category` class like `cat = Category.find(...); cat.PrimerasDosNoVacias`, but it looks like you're trying to call it as a class method, e.g. `Category.PrimerasDosNoVacias`. To declare a class method, you must use `def self.PrimerasDosNoVaicas`. *However*, it's very rare for a method name in Ruby to be "CamelCased"—I suggest sticking to Ruby conventions and using `def self.primeras_dos_no_vacias`.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at this Ruby style guide for more information on making your code more readable and idiomatic: https://github.com/styleguide/ruby

Answer (score 0):

The Problem would be calling `Category.PrimerasDosNoVacias` since you are calling directly on the class it is supposed to be a `Class` method , hence please try :-

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy
    validates_uniqueness_of :nombre 
    class << self
        def PrimerasDosNoVacias
            cant=0
            aux =0
            cate=["",""]
            categorias = Category.where(eliminado: false)
            while (categorias.length >= aux && cant < 2) 
                if (Article.where(category_id: categorias[aux].id).length != 0)
                    cate=categorias[aux]
                    cant+=1
                end 
                aux+=1
            end
        end
    end
end
```