# Implementing quick sort with Ruby

Tags: ruby, quicksort

I wrote code for quick sort. I am getting an error for my sorting method but I don't see where the problem is

```
def sort (numbers, first, last)
if first >= last
    return
end

if first < last 
    pivot = first
    j = first
    k = last

    while (j < k) 
        if(numbers[j] >= numbers[pivot])
            j +=1 
            if(numbers[k] < numbers[pivot]) 
                k -=1 
                if(j <= k) 
                    temp = numbers[j]
                    numbers[j] = numbers[k]
                    numbers[k] = temp
                end
            end
        end
    end
    puts "end loop"
    temp = numbers[pivot]
    numbers[pivot]= numbers[k]
    numbers[k] = temp
    sort(numbers,first,k-1)
    sort(numbers,k+1,last)
end
end

a = [89, 23, 12, 67, 45, 78, 24, 56, 87, 73, 37] 
first = 0

for i in 0...a.length
puts a[i]
end

last = a.length - 1
puts "Array Count is #{last}"

sort(a, 0, last)

for i in 0...a.length
puts a[i]
end
```

error : `sort': undefined method`+@' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
Can anyone tell me what is this error about

Comment: To start, replace `j++` with `j += 1` and `k--` with `k -= 1`.

[why ruby doesn't have ++ operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660563/why-doesnt-ruby-support-i-or-i-increment-decrement-operators)

Comment: I'd suspect that one of your sublists is empty as would happen when k is either 1 or the list length.

Comment: Please give the full text of the error, including line numbers and backtrace. All I know from this is that somewhere you tried to add to a nil value. Also please try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please change `j++` and `k--` as @TJ notes, rerun the code and if you still have an error, edit your question to reflect the updated information. When you report an exception, please  also indicate the line on which it occurred. If I were you, I'd delete the question, make the changes, then undelete.

Comment: I replaced j++ with j +=1 and same with k but when i run it after "array Count is 10" it goes to hang state. I have to terminate the program by pressing Ctrl+C

Comment: That's happening because you are missing the code needed to stop the recursion (an `if` clause).

Comment: if first = last then it will stop the recursion

Comment: yes I mean that, if it is not correct what else i can implement

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is working on my computer (with fixing few errors with ++ operators). There must be some problem with how you are running the file.
Secondly the code doesn't really look like Ruby code (like ruby doesn't have ++ operator). Check out my sample implementation - [Quick Sort](https://gist.github.com/hspandher/6334090)

Comment: How could the code be working on your computer, considering that it contains `j++` and `k--`?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I replaced j++ with j +=1 and same with k but when i run it after "array Count is 10" it goes to hang state. I have to terminate the program by pressing Ctrl+C