# Overwrite a variable without repeating the name

Tags: ruby, performance

Is there a method to overwrite variable without copying its name? For example, when I want to change `my_var = '3'` to an integer, I must do something like this:

```
my_var = my_var.to_i
```

Is there way to do this without copying variable's name? I want to do something like this:

```
my_var = something_const.to_i
```

For numbers there exists `+=`, `-=` etc, but is there universal way to do this for all methods ?

Comment: There is no universal `.=` if that is what you are asking. Why do you need that though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to covert a string to an integer like that, without repeating the variable name. Methods such as `String#upcase!` and `Array#flatten!` work by *mutating* the object; however, it is not possible to define such a method like `String#to_i!` because we are converting the object to an instance of a **different class**.

For example, here is a (failed) attempt to define such a method:

```
# What I want to be able to do:
# my_var = "123"
# my_var.to_i! # => my_var == 123

class String
  def to_i!
    replace(Integer(self))
  end
end

my_var = "123"
my_var.to_i! # TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
```

...And even if this code were valid, it would still offer no performance gain since a new object is still being created.

As for your examples of `+=` and `-=`, these are in fact simply shorthand for:

```
x += 1
# Is equivalent to:
x = x + 1
```

So again, there is no *performance* gain here either; just slightly nicer syntax. A good question to ask is, [why doesn't ruby support a `++` operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660563/why-doesnt-ruby-support-i-or-i-increment-decrement-operators) If such an operator existed then it **would** offer performance gain... But I'll let you research for yourself why this is missing from the language.

So to summarise,

> is there universal way to do this for all methods?

No. The special operators like `+=`, `-=`, `|=` and `&=` are all predefined; there is no "generalised" version such as `method_name=`.

You can also define methods that mutate the object, but only when appropriate. Such methods are usually named with a `!`, are called "bang-methods", and have a "non-bang" counterpart. On `String` objects, for example, there is [`String#capitalize!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-capitalize-21) (and `String#capitalize`), [`String#delete!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-delete-21) (and `String#delete`), [`String#encode!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-encode-21) (and `String#encode`), .... but no `String#to_i!` for the reasons discussed above.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit hard to give an "example" to an impossible problem ;) ... Perhaps your idea of using `String#replace` is a better try, but it still fails with: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with your suggestion, thanks :)