# why "loop do" throws void value error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I'm using in my opinion trivial code, like this one

```
loop do 

    i++

    break if i > 5

end
```

but when I try to run I'll get `void value expression break if i > 5`

what am I doing wrong? What does this error mean?

Comment: i++ isn't valid in ruby.  Try i += i

Comment: @Doon, that's not correct. Rather, `i++` is simply not the same as `i += 1`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i++` may be perfectly valid. For example,

```
1++ 3
  #=> 4
1++

3
  #=> 4
```

That's because both of these expressions are parsed to

```
1 + +3
```

and then to

```
1 + 3
  #=> 4
```

Your expression is therefore equivalent to

```
loop do 
  i + (break if i > 5)
end
```

A `void value` exception was raised because `break if i > 5` does not return a value.

You want

```
i = 0
loop do 
  i += 1
  break if i > 5
end
i #=> 6
```

or (my preference)

```
i = 0
loop do 
  i += 1
  raise StopIteration if i > 5
end
i #=> 6
```

[Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) handles the `StopIteration` exception by breaking out of the loop.

Comment: Wow that's perfectly well explained. Thank you. Your answer provides the best explanation of my problem, why it is happening and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

```
i = 0
loop do
  i += 1
  break if i > 5
end
```

Comment: Good answer. We can also write `loop.with_index { |_,i| raise StopIteration if i > 5 }`.

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think `i++` on its own is valid Ruby code?

Although Ruby syntax is  often easy to guess, don't assume it resembles other language constructs.

Ruby also has much better patterns to do things. My second example is an example of what you want.

```
i = 0
loop do 
    i = i + 1 # or shorthand i += 1
    puts i
    break if i > 5
end
```

In reality this counts to 6. Your `break` should be at the beginning.

A better way

```
1.upto 5 do |i|
 puts i
end
```

This counts to 5.

Comment: `(1..5).each { |i| puts i }` is quite nice too.

Comment: yes and for a onle line recommended but I doubt in the case of the OP and for a beginner it's not so clear

Comment: The OP may think `i++` is valid Ruby code because it is! :-)

Comment: not in the way eg java uses it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660563/why-doesnt-ruby-support-i-or-i-increment-decrement-operators about Matz opinion about this operator 1++1 is justy the same as 1+1

Comment: I think you meant "`i++` is not the same as `i = i+1`", but that's not what you said.

Comment: have added 'on its own' to avoid confusion about what I meant 8:) Thnx Cary