# syntax error-unexpected keyword else ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax-error, atom-editor

i am getting this error while trying to execute this piece of code

```
def self.encode(string)
    v=string.split("")
    num=0
    tmp=v[0]
    s=""
    for i in (0..v.count-1)
      if v[i]==tmp
        num++
      else
        s << num
        s<<v[i-1]
        tmp=v[i]
        num=1
      end
    end
    return s
  end
```

the error is run-length-encoding.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else

Comment: http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/ruby/ruby-talk/2710

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3660563/438992

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`++` operator doesn't exist in Ruby. Go for

```
num += 1
```