# Unclear syntax error in Ruby : "syntax error, unexpected end" when using an invalid operator

Tags: ruby, syntax

I am trying to make sense of why Ruby reported the syntax error that it did , and why it could not be more clear. The following code snippet is giving me a "syntax error, unexpected end"

```rb
# @param {NestedInteger[]} nested_list
# @return {Integer}
def depth_sum(nested_list)
  queue = Queue.new

  nested_list.each { |element| queue.enq element }

  result = 0
  level  = 1
  until queue.empty?
    size = queue.size
    size.times do
      element = queue.pop
      if element.is_integer
        result += level * element.get_Integer
      else
        element.each { |elem| queue.enq(elem) }
      end
    end
    level++
  end
end
```

I then figured out that Ruby does not have the ++ operator , so i replaced level++ with level+=1 and the code worked. But why was Ruby's syntax error message so cryptic about an unexpected end when in fact my error was not due to the "end" but because I was using a ++ operator which is not used in Ruby.

Comment: There's no such `++` operator in Ruby. Try with `level += 1`.

Comment: See [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660563/why-doesnt-ruby-support-i-or-i-increment-decrement-operators).

Comment: It's probably because `1 ++ 1` is parsed as `1 + ( +1)`, so it needs the second operand but the Ruby met `end` at its place in your example, hence the error. But it's only my supposition.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, it is allowed to have whitespace between an operator and its operand(s). This includes newlines, and it includes unary prefix operators. So, the following is perfectly valid Ruby:

```rb
+
foo
```

It is the same as

```rb
+ foo
```

which is the same as

```rb
+foo
```

which is the same as

```rb
foo.+@()
```

The following is also perfectly valid Ruby:

```rb
foo++
bar
```

It is the same as

```rb
foo ++ bar
```

which is the same as

```rb
foo + + bar
```

which is the same as

```rb
foo + +bar
```

which is the same as

```rb
foo.+(bar.+@())
```

So, as you can see, the line

```rb
level++
```

on its own is *not* syntactically invalid. It is the `end` on the *next* line that makes this invalid. Which is exactly what the error message says: you are using the unary prefix `+` operator, so Ruby is expecting the operand, but instead finds an `end` it was not expecting.